# Does $log(n)^k = O(\sqrt{n})$ for any $k$?

Tags: analysis, asymptotics

I want to know if there exists a $N_0$, $C$, such that $\forall n \geq N_0, log(n)^k \leq C \sqrt{n}$? I'm curious about the actual quantities of $C, N_0$ in terms of $k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $n=e^m$, then the inequality becomes $$m^k \le e^{m/2}$$
Taking $k^\text{th}$ roots, we get $$m\le e^{m/2k}=(e^{1/2k})^m$$
This reaches equality at $$m=-2k W(-1/2k)$$
where $W$ denotes the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).
For example, given $k=2$, we [get](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-4*W(-1%2F4)) $m\approx 1.4296118$.  For all $m$ past this value, the inequality will hold.

Note that for small $k$ (e.g. $k=1$), equality will never hold; the inequality will be strict for all $n$.

Answer (score 3):

General result:

> For any $\alpha,\,\beta>0$, $\;\log^\alpha n=o\bigl(n^\beta\bigr)$.

So *a fortiori*, $\;\log^\alpha n=O\bigl(n^\beta\bigr)$.

The assertion is easy to prove: set $x=n^{\beta/\alpha}\iff n=x^{\alpha/\beta}$. Then
$$\frac{\log^\alpha n}{n^\beta}=\frac{\log^\alpha x^{\alpha/\beta}}{x^\alpha}=\Bigl(\frac\alpha\beta\Bigr)^\alpha\biggl(\frac{\log x}{x}\biggr)^\alpha,$$
so it comes down to the high school limit $\;\dfrac{\log x}x\to 0\;$ as $\;x\to+\infty$.